# Setting up bundles with grouped product options

Tags: extensions, custom-options, bundled-product, grouped-products

I have bundle products that need importing into Magento from another e-commerce store. The products are customisable gift bags, an example product might look like:

Gift Bag 1
includes

item 1

item 2

Choose either

Item 3

Item 4

Item 5 + 6

Item 7

Custom option 1 e.g how the bag is tied

Custom option 2

I was experimenting with the built in Magento bundles but what I need doesn't seem to be possible as only simple products can be choices in the bundle. i.e the "Item 5 + 6" choice wouldn't be possible.

The price of the product needs to be the combination of products chosen, plus any custom options.

Is this format possible using default Magento? If not, are there any extensions that allow this kind of functionality?